# Drag a file into the app window

Tags: haxe, openfl

I'd like to make an app that can process a user selected file. But instead of just clicking a button and selecting the file, I'd like to make a feature where the user simply drags the file in the window of my app and then it loads the file and does the processing.

I can't find how to do this within Haxe API or OpenFL API, perhaps someone knows how to implement that.

I would like to target Windows, Mac and Neko platforms if it helps with anything.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678405%28v=vs.85%29.aspx can be used on Windows.

Comment: You should try [OpenFL forum](http://community.openfl.org/) to see if its possible or even planned in the future.